# Expanded version of Eddington's puzzle with 4 players

Tags: probability, puzzle

There are four people $X,Y,Z,K$ who speak the truth with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ independently of each other. Given $X$ claimed that $Y$ denied that $Z$ declared that $K$ lied. Find the probability that $K$ speaks the truth?

**My attempt:** I plan to imitate the solution given in this post - [Eddington's controversy simplified](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539702/eddingtons-controversy-simplified) - but in our case, we have a lot more cases ($16$). I wonder if anyone has any thoughts for a slicker solutions, rather than brute-forcing? Also, I am confused if the word "claimed" is definite (aka. does it imply $X$ always speak the truth?)

Comment: "does it imply X always speak the truth?"  Of course not.  If I claimed I was a hard boiled egg.... I'd be lying.

Comment: @fleablood Lol...thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do the 16 options.  Just the ones where $K$ is telling the truth.

If $X$ is lying the we don't know, don't care what $Y,Z$ say. So the option is $X$ lying; $K$ (independently) telling truth.

If $X$ is telling the truth and $Y$ is lying then we know don't know, don't care what $Z$ says.  So the options is $X$ truth, $Y$ lying, and $K$ (independently) telling the truth.

If $X$ is telling the truth and $Y$ is telling the truth and $Z$ is lying, the $K$ must have the truth.  So the option is $X$ truth, $Y$ truth, $Z$ lying.

Those are the only three options that matter.  Calculate them and add them up.

All other options $X$ lying and $K$ independently lying; $X$ truth $Y$ lying and $K$ independently lying;   ad $X$ truth, $Y$ truth, $Z$ truth so $K$ must be lying-- are all $K$ lying.

If $X$ is lying, it doesn't matter what $Y$ and $Z$ do.  That removes $4$ cases.  If $X$ is truth but $Y$ is lying it doesn't matter what $Z$ does.  That removes $2$ cases.  And if $X$ and $Y$ are telling the true the $K$ telling the truth is entirely on $Z$ so that removes $2$.